# JavaFX boolean property naming convention

Tags: java, javafx, properties, naming-conventions

I know the normal convention for boolean properties is to use an adjective for the property itself, and use "is" for getter and "set" for setter.

Example:

```
private final BooleanProperty edible;
private final BooleanProperty edibleProperty()
{
    return this.edible;
}
private final boolean isEdible()
{
    return this.edibleProperty().get();
}
private final void setEdible(final boolean value)
{
    this.edibleProperty().set(value);
}
```

Now I have a property that is about whether something exists. The name that naturally come to my mind is "hasSomething". However, the getter "isHasSomething" would not make sense. What should be the correct way to name my property in this case?

### Edit

To make it clearer, I'll give an example:

```
private final BooleanProperty hasAdminRight;
private final BooleanProperty hasAdminRightProperty()
{
    return this.hasAdminRight;
}
private final boolean isHasAdminRight()
{
    return this.hasAdminRightProperty().get();
}
private final void setHasAdminRight(final boolean value)
{
    this.hasAdminRightProperty().set(value);
}
```

The code above would run perfectly fine. However, notice that the getter `isHasAdminRight` sounds weird (unless I am the only one down here who think that it is weird). Of course, changing it to `get` would work (run) as well, but `getHasAdminRight` is also somewhat weird.

Is there any naming convention that I can adopt, `.*AdminRight.*`, such that it sounds correct? Or, everyone here would simply use `hasAdminRight` with the getter `isHasAdminRight` / `getHasAdminRight`, as it is supposed to be the convention?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getHasSomething()` rather than `isHasSomething()`.

Logic in JavaFX that works based upon reflective naming such as [PropertyValueFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) works with either `is` or `get` prefixes on the getter names.  So you could use either of those and it would work fine.  The logic doesn't care if the return type is a boolean or not, it just first checks for a `get` prefix and, if it can't find that, then checks for an `is` prefix.  However, the same logic wouldn't understand `hasSomething()` to be a getter as it is not prefixed by `get` or `is`.

Comment: Hmm, I am aware that the properties' getters and setters need to start with get/is and set respectively. However, I am more concerned about the naming convention used for properties that store the information whether something exists.

Comment: I fail to understand the distinction you are drawing.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: My answer remains the same (use `getHasSomething()`), I don't have a better suggestion.